# How to add numbers occuring in a text?

Tags: calculations

How make LaTeX to remember some numbers and output the total sum by calling another command? Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

The price of the first item is \pr{10.23}, that of the second item is 

\pr{2.30}. 

%% The command \pr{10.23} should print the number 10.23 (perhaps with unit) and then remember it for the total sum.    

The total so far  is \prsum the overall total sum is \prallsum.
%% should print 12.53 and 14.86.
There is another item about \pr{2.33}. 

Not the total sum so far is \prsum and the overall total sum is \prallsum

%% This should print 14.86 in both cases.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution using the [`minifp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minifp) package and some `aux` file magic (and so you need to run the file through `latex` twice to get the correct values).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minifp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@subtotal{0}
\newcommand*\pr[1]{%
    #1%
    \MFPadd{\@subtotal}{#1}\@subtotal\relax%
    \MFPstrip{\@subtotal}\@subtotal}
\newcommand*\prsum{\@subtotal}
\def\student@allsum{???}
\gdef\prallsum{\student@allsum}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\student@allsum{\@subtotal}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
The price of the first item is \pr{10.23}, that of the second item is 

\pr{2.30}. 


The total so far  is \prsum{} the overall total sum is \prallsum.
There is another item about \pr{2.33}. 

Not the total sum so far is \prsum{} and the overall total sum is \prallsum.
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Discussion

The command

```
\newcommand*\pr[1]{%
    #1%
    \MFPadd{\@subtotal}{#1}\@subtotal\relax%
    \MFPstrip{\@subtotal}\@subtotal}
```

defines the `\pr` macro, so that it first prints the input value (assumed to be a decimal number}, and adds it to the subtotal using the `\MFPadd` function of the `minifp` package. It then strips the trailing zeros using the `\MFPstrip` function. (Side note: `minifp` performs fixed-point arithmetic with up to 8 decimal places.)

The command `\prsum` just prints the subtotal; noticed that in the course of the text I've edited your file to use `\prsum{}` instead, to avoide the macro gobbling up the space afterwards. If you are only using `\prsum` in text, you can use [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) to circumvent this need.

To print the overall total sum, what we do is, at the end of the document (when you write `\end{document}`, write to the `.aux` file the current subtotal. We do this by writing it as a command definition: after running `pdflatex` on your file, the `.aux` file should contain the line

```
\gdef\student@allsum{14.86}
```

This line is read back into the stream around `\begin{document}` (when the `aux` file is read), and so overwrites the original definition of `\student@allsum` to be `???`. We have to include an original definition because, before the first pass of `pdflatex`, the command `\student@allsum` would otherwise be undefined (since the `aux` file is generated during the run, and is not available to be read before the first run).

Notice that this means, like resolving label-references, that to update the correct value from `\prallsum` you need to run `pdflatex` at least **twice** after changing the file.

Comment: This is a really nice answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new:N \g_student_sum_fp
\fp_new:N \g_student_total_fp

\NewDocumentCommand{\pr}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { #1 } % print the value
  \fp_gadd:Nn \g_student_sum_fp { #1 } % add to the global container
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\prsum}{}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { \g_student_sum_fp }
 }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\prallsum}{}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { \g_student_total_fp }
 }

\AtEndDocument
 {
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
   {
    \ExplSyntaxOn ^^J
    \fp_gset:Nn \exp_not:N \g_student_total_fp { \fp_eval:n { \g_student_sum_fp } } ^^J
    \ExplSyntaxOff ^^J
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

The price of the first item is \pr{10.23}, that of the second item is 
\pr{2.30}. 

The total so far is \prsum{} and the overall total sum is \prallsum.

There is another item about \pr{2.33}. 

Now the total sum so far is \prsum{} and the overall total sum is \prallsum.


\end{document}
```

The macros should be sufficiently clear: `\pr` prints the given value and updates the total; at end document, the total is written in a suitable way in the aux file.

[image]

A warning might be added if the values of `\g_student_sum_fp` and `\g_student_total_fp` are different, telling the user that a new LaTeX run is needed: change the code from `\AtEndDocument` to `\ExplSyntaxOff` into

```
\AtEndDocument
 {
  \iow_now:cx { @auxout }
   {
    \ExplSyntaxOn ^^J
    \fp_gset:Nn \exp_not:N \g_student_total_fp { \fp_eval:n { \g_student_sum_fp } } ^^J
    \ExplSyntaxOff ^^J
   }
  \fp_compare:nF { \g_student_sum_fp = \g_student_total_fp }
   {
    \msg_warning:nn { student/sum } { rerun }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnn { student/sum } { rerun }
 {
  Value~for~\exp_not:N \prallsum has~changed.~Rerun~LaTeX
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In case the value has changed from the previous run, you get the warning

```
*************************************************
* student/sum warning: "rerun"
* 
* Value for \prallsum has changed. Rerun LaTeX
*************************************************
```